Find ordered bases $B$,$C$ when $[T]_{C,B}$ = 3 $*$ 3 identity matrix
Find ordered bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ of the linear transformation such that $[T]_{\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{B}}$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.
Consider the real linear transformation $T: P_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $T(p) = (p(0), p(1), p(-1))$ for $p = p(x) \in P_2(\mathbb{R})$. Find ordered bases $\mathcal{B}$ of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $[T]_{\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{B}}$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, or prove that this is not possible.
I have calculated the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the standard bases $\{1, x, x^2\}$ of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\{\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j}, \mathbf{k}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
However, I am confused about how the bases $\mathcal{B} = \{1, x, x^2\}$ and $\mathcal{C} = \{(1, 1, 1), (0, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1)\}$ result in the identity matrix. Could someone explain the solution process for this problem?

what are the basis for your representation of T?

@Exodd  the matrix representation of $T$ is respect to the standard bases ${1, x, x^2}$ of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and ${\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j}, \mathbf{k}}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$

how do you write the basis of $\mathbb R^3$ with respect to $\mathcal C$?

Suppose we start with the basis $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$ for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$, then the transformation $T$ does the following:
$$T(1)=(1,1,1,), \quad T(x)=(0,1,-1), \quad T(x^2)=(0,1,1).$$
Observe that $\{(1,1,1), \, (0,1-1), (0,1,1)\}=\{u,v,w\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, if were to choose this as basis $\mathcal{C}$, then
\begin{align*}
T(1)&=u=\color{red}{1}u+0v+0w\\
T(x)&=v=0u+\color{red}{1}v+0w\\
T(x^2)&=w=0u+0v+\color{red}{1}w
\end{align*}
Then the transformation matrix is the identity matrix.

Can $B$ and $C$ be other possible bases? Specifically, assume the basis for $B$ is ${1 + 2x, 3x, x^2}$, is it possible for $[T]_{C,B}$ to be the $3 * 3$ identity matrix?

@YukaiHUA It is possible. With your example basis $T(1+2x)=(1,3,-1), T(3x)=(0,3,-3)$ and $T(x^2)=(0,1,1)$. Note that the image vectors still form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, if we take $u=(1,3,-1)$, $v=(0,3-3)$ and $w=(0,1,1)$. Then with ${u,v,w}$ as basis, we get that the matrix representation for $T$ is an identity matrix.
